# User icons fail to load in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, firefox

In Firefox 66.0.1 (and for a few versions by now), many user icons fail to load on Stack Exchange pages. For example, on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194585/anime-cartoon-with-kids-battling-with-robots-in-a-game), the asker's icon and the icon for the writer of [(currently) the only answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194585/anime-cartoon-with-kids-battling-with-robots-in-a-game/207780#207780) fail to load, while with Jenayah, the most recent editor of the question, her icon loads.

This problem doesn't occur on Chrome. Right-clicking and reloading the images doesn't work; viewing them in a new tab shows that the browser is able to display the files. This may be a problem with Stack Exchange's inner workings cooperating with Firefox, or something may just be wrong with my download of the browser.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 66

Comment: As covered in the linked dupe, for one reason or another, the effect is your own filtering features.

Comment: Not observed on Windows 10 Home and Firefox 66.0.1 (up-to-date).